# PYXB - Generation of namespace groups requires generate-to-files

Tags: python, pyxb

PYXB - When generating class definitions at runtime, iam facing following expection

```
import pyxb.binding.generate

path = "E:/schema/schema.xsd"
code = pyxb.binding.generate.GeneratePython(schema_location=path)
rv = compile(code, 'test', 'exec')
xsd = eval(rv)
```

above code gives this error

```
raise pyxb.BindingGenerationError('Generation of namespace groups requires generate-to-files')
pyxb.exceptions_.BindingGenerationError: Generation of namespace groups requires generate-to-file
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the PyXB help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyxb/discussion/956708/thread/d1b6f062/) where somebody coincidently asked exactly this same question at the same time.  Odd.

Comment: that was me actually.